Exclude Directory or File in gopls
I have generated file using gqlgen in my go project, but it caused to display warning (I think it is produced by gopls) that is kinda obstructive:

// app/api/graphql/graph/generated.go

func (ec *executionContext) marshalNBoolean2bool(ctx context.Context, sel ast.SelectionSet, v bool) graphql.Marshaler {
    res := graphql.MarshalBoolean(v)
    if res == graphql.Null {
        if !graphql.HasFieldError(ctx, graphql.GetFieldContext(ctx)) {
            ec.Errorf(ctx, "the requested element is null which the schema does not allow")
        }
    }
    return res
}

The error is in this part:
unused parameter: sel
unused parameter: selunusedparamsunusedparams
var sel ast.SelectionSet

The go app is still running, but it causes vscode linter to display error, very annoying.
Is there a way to exclude that directory or path to be ignored or excluded by `gopls?
I know there is discussion about it, but it seems they closed / rejected it without giving any solution:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37697
I have tried adding this in my .vscode/settings.json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
  "go.formatTool": "default",
  "go.lintTool": "golangci-lint", <= this part
  "go.lintOnSave": "package",
  "go.lintFlags": [
    "--fast",
  ],
  ...


And in the golangci-lint.yml
exclude-dirs:
  - ./app/api/graphql/graph/generated.go

Seems like that only excludes the file from golangci-lint run, not from gopls static checking that causes to display error in vscode...
In .vscode/settings.json I also tried this too based on this doc and still not working...
  "gopls": {
    "ui.completion.usePlaceholders": true,
    "ui.diagnostic.diagnosticsTrigger": "Edit",
    "ui.diagnostic.staticcheck": true,
    "ui.documentation.hoverKind": "SynopsisDocumentation",
    "formatting.gofumpt": false,
    "build.directoryFilters": [
      "-app/api/graphql/graph" <= this part
    ]
  },

